# Rewrite rule does not work

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want my URL to be like `http://www.domainname.com/Seagate-abc-Buyout-22.html` but my rewrite rules do not apply. Do you spot anything wrong?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.Domainname\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /final.php?title=$1&sid=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't work because your regex is incorrect:

```
 `^([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$` cannot match `Seagate-abc-Buyout-22.html`
```

Try changing your rule to:

```
 RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^.]*)\.html$ /final.php?title=$1&sid=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This will internally rewrite above URL to `/index.php?title=Seagate&sid=abc-Buyout-22`